# How can I use UTF8 characters in Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

creating a simple model with a migration like the following will break the rake db:migrate tasks:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.float :price, :default => "0.00"
      t.string :currency, :default => "€"

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Exchanging the Euro sign with `EUR` fixes the issue temporary but in general I'd love to understand how I could work with `€` as default value there.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this on the first line of your migration file:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Comment: wow that surprises me ... I thought that's something I won't see again once I leave the PHP world ... anyway thanks

Comment: @pagid the encoding magic comment is kinda universal: vim, emacs, Python, etc.